# Is there a way to set mysql variables using the JDBC Connector?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

In Java, of course. I need to enable "force", but I have no idea how. I'm sure it might go somewhere in the URL, but I've tried a bunch of different things and looked for a bit on Google, to no avail.

Comment: Could you clarify your question?

Comment: Sure. When I execute a a number of ALTER TABLE queries in mysql from the command prompt, not all the tables queried exist (yet. but they will). So in order to force mysql to continue through all the queries, I use the -f variable when launching it. (ie. mysql -f -uuser -ppassword SCHEMA_NAME < queries.sql). I'm trying to replicate that "force" variable in Java using the JDBC.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to do that in your java code, by catching SQL exception on each alter statement and ignoring it and moving on to the next one. I would check for some unique property of the SQL exception (class, message content) that happens in that situation, and rethrow (or wrap and rethrow) the SQL exception if it isn't what an alter table throws you aren't swallowing problems.